# Solving $x^p-x-1=0$ with Lagrange Inversion Formula

Tags: complex-analysis, pattern-recognition, lagrange-inversion

I am working through the proof that one can solve quintic equations first by reducing the polynomial to one of the form $x^5-x-t$, and then solving $x^5-x-t=0$ using the Lagrange Inversion Formula on the function $x-x^5$. However, to do this it seems as if I need to be able to compute $n$th derivatives of 
$$
\left(\frac{x}{x-x^5}\right)^n,
$$
which I am unable to get a nice closed form for. Could anyone offer some insight into this? Thanks.

Comment: [Lagrange inversion theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem) in Wikipedia seems to deal exactly with the example you're willing to cover.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I have looked there. Wikipedia basically says "this can be solved using Lagrange Inversion, and the answer is this."  I am looking to actually go through the details.

Comment: Oh, wait, did my answer actually solve everything for you?  :O

Comment: Well, good for you!  (I'm still not done figuring out how to get there)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that

$$\begin{align}\left(\frac x{x-x^5}\right)^n&=(1-x^4)^{-n}\\&=1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\Gamma(n+k)}{k!\Gamma(n)}x^{4k}\end{align}$$

By binomial expansion.  Thus,

$$\begin{align}\frac{d^r}{dx^r}\left(\frac x{x-x^5}\right)^n&=\frac{d^r}{dx^r}1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\Gamma(n+k)}{k!\Gamma(n)}x^{4k}\\&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(4k)!\Gamma(n+k)}{(4k-r)!k!\Gamma(n)}x^{4k-r}\\&=r!\sum_{k=1}^\infty\binom{4k}{r}\binom{n+k}{n}x^{4k-r}\\\end{align}$$

where $\frac1{(4k-r)!}=0$ when $r>4k$

Comment: True. Your idea is better.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla You inspired my brain to think better :D So you can get half credit ;)

Answer (score 3):

Hint: do a partial fraction decomposition:

$$\frac{x}{x-x^5} = \frac{1}{1-x^4} = \frac{A}{x-1} + \frac{B}{x+1} +  \frac{C}{x-i} + \frac{D}{x+i}.$$

Comment: Wow, that's a good idea!  But how do you tackle it raised to the $n$th power?

Comment: @SimpleArt, multinomial theorem.

Comment: Has to be an easier way IMO